# Changing the height of a div if a class exists inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to increase the height of `.custom-main-container1` when you click on `#tblHideShow`, if the `.collapsing` class exists inside the `#collapsableTable` div.

```js
$('#tblHideShow').click(function() {
  $('#collapsableTable').toggleClass('collapsing');

  if ($('#collapsableTable').hasClass('collapsing')) {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.custom-main-container1').css("height", "calc(100% - 241px)");
  } else {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.custom-main-container1').css("height", "calc(100% - 314px)");
  }
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-main-container1">
  div content here
</div>
<div class="xyz" id="collapsableTable">
  div content here
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="abc" id="tblHideShow">table collapse</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I placed your code in to a snippet where it is working absolutely fine, as you can verify with the DOM inspector tool. The UI doesn't update because 100% height doesn't work unless all parent elements have an explicit height set on them.

Comment: I have updated the snippet to set a `height` on the `body` and `html` elements to that the CSS update now has an effect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right your problem the following codesnipped will work for you:

```js
 
$('#tblHideShow').click(function() {
  $('#collapsableTable').toggleClass('collapsing');

  if ($('#collapsableTable').hasClass('collapsing')) {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.custom-main-container1').css("height", "200px");
  }else {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.custom-main-container1').css("height", "100px");
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-main-container1{
 height:200px;
 background-color: #45b6fe;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px; 
}

.xyz{
 background-color: #daf0ff;
 height:100px;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.collapsing{
 display:none;
}

.class2>#class1{
 text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-main-container1">
  Changeable Hight div content here
</div>
<div class="xyz collapsing" id="collapsableTable">
   Collapseable div content here
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="abc" id="tblHideShow">table collapse</a>
</div>
```